# WPF DataGrid Multithreading Crash

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datatable, wpfdatagrid

I have a View with a `DataGrid` in it.
A ViewModel as `DataContext` where i can access a `DataTable` in a background object.
The background object has to work with the `DataTable` and keep it updated.
The user has also be allowed to make changes to that `DataTable`.

If i create a copy of the `DataTable` it stops crashing but the user is obviousely not working on the data.

If i leave access open for the user the program crashed inevitabely.

Here is a short program that will crash:

app.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        SomeBackgroundThing background = new SomeBackgroundThing();
        MainWindowViewModel viewmodel = new MainWindowViewModel(background);
        MainWindowView view = new MainWindowView(viewmodel);
        view.Show();
    }
}
```

main xaml

```
<Window x:Class="NullPointerDataGrid.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="datagrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=table, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the program code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace NullPointerDataGrid
{
    public partial class MainWindowView : Window
    {
        public MainWindowView(MainWindowViewModel model)
        {
            DataContext = model;
            InitializeComponent();
            datagrid.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ScrollToBottom);
            datagrid.AutoGeneratedColumns += new EventHandler(StarSizeLastRow);

        }

    void ScrollToBottom(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TableGrid_ScrollToBottom");
        if (datagrid.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(datagrid, 0) as Decorator;
            if (border != null)
            {
                var scroll = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
                if (scroll != null) scroll.ScrollToEnd();
            }
        }

    }

    void StarSizeLastRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TableGrid_StarSizeLastColumn");
        try
        {
            datagrid.Columns[datagrid.Columns.Count - 1].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    }

public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private SomeBackgroundThing thing;
    public DataTable table
    {
        get
        {
            lock (thing.table)
            {
                //DataTable wpfcopy = thing.table.Copy();
                return thing.table;
            };
        }
        set
        {
            Debug.Write("This never happens");
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel(SomeBackgroundThing thing)
    {
        this.thing = thing;
        thing.Changed += new EventHandler(thing_Changed);
    }

    void thing_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("table"));
        }
    }
}

public class SomeBackgroundThing : IDisposable
{
    public DataTable table;
    private DataTable tablecopy;
    private System.Timers.Timer timer, slowrowchanger;

    public event EventHandler Changed = new EventHandler((o, e) => { ;});
    protected void CallChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Changed(sender, e);
    }

    public SomeBackgroundThing()
    {
        CreateTable();
        UpdateB(this, null);
        tablecopy = table.Copy();
        InitAndStartTimer(1);
    }

    #region timer

    private void UpdateA()
    {
        Boolean haschanged = false;
        DataTable newcopy = table.Copy(); ;
        if (newcopy.Rows.Count != tablecopy.Rows.Count)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Different ammount of rows");
            haschanged = true;
        }
        else if (newcopy.Columns.Count != tablecopy.Columns.Count)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Different ammount of columns");
            haschanged = true;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newcopy.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < newcopy.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (newcopy.Rows[i][j].ToString() != tablecopy.Rows[i][j].ToString())
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(
                            "Element [{0}/{1}]: {2} is different from {3}",
                            i, j, newcopy.Rows[i][j], tablecopy.Rows[i][j]
                            ));
                        haschanged = true;
                    }
                    if (haschanged) break;
                }
                if (haschanged) break;
            }
        }
        if (haschanged)
        {
            tablecopy = newcopy;
        }
    }

    private void InitAndStartTimer(int interval)
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = interval;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((s, e) =>
        {
            UpdateA();
        });
        timer.Enabled = true;

        slowrowchanger = new System.Timers.Timer();
        slowrowchanger.Interval = 3000;
        slowrowchanger.AutoReset = true;
        slowrowchanger.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((s, e) =>
        {
            UpdateB(null, null);
        });
        slowrowchanger.Enabled = true;

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        slowrowchanger.Enabled = false;
        timer.Dispose();
        slowrowchanger.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion

    #region editlastrow

    void UpdateB(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        List<String> cells = new List<string>{
                "The SAME", 
                rnd.Next(0,100).ToString(), 
                rnd.ToString(), 
                rnd.NextDouble().ToString()};
        lock (table)
        {
            OverwriteOrAppendLastRow(ref table, cells);
            table.AcceptChanges();
        }
        CallChanged(this, null);
    }

    private void OverwriteOrAppendLastRow(ref DataTable table, List<string> newrow)
    {
        if (table.Rows.Count == 0) CreteEmptyRow(ref table);
        if (newrow[0].ToString() != table.Rows[table.Rows.Count - 1][0].ToString())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Creating row because '{0}' is different from '{1}'", newrow[0], table.Rows[table.Rows.Count - 1][0]));
            CreteEmptyRow(ref table);
        }
        OverwriteLastRow(ref table, newrow);
    }

    private void OverwriteLastRow(ref DataTable table, List<string> newrow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < newrow.Count() && i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            table.Rows[table.Rows.Count - 1][i] = newrow[i];
        }
    }

    private void CreteEmptyRow(ref DataTable table)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(new String[table.Columns.Count]);
    }

    #endregion

    private void CreateTable()
    {
        table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("FirstCell", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("BananaCell", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("CherryCell", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("Blue", typeof(String));
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 145; i++)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(new String[]{
                rnd.Next().ToString(), 
                rnd.Next(0,i+1).ToString(), 
                rnd.ToString(), 
                rnd.NextDouble().ToString()});
        }
    }

}

}
```

How can i stop this multithread crashing?

---

EDIT:

I don't know if there are more than one reasons for this code to crash. But i did my best to gather some information about one reason to crash:

Nullpointer exception in App.g.cs - the autogenerated portion. The Debugger wont step into it - so i cant say anything about the line it crashes in.

Here is the Exception Detail, sorry for the German.

```
System.NullReferenceException wurde nicht behandelt.
  Message=Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  InnerException:
```

The Stacktrace only shows "Externer Code" so no stack to trace.

The thing is that WPF crashes - my code can handle it... somehow i need to capsule WPF so it wont crash, one way to do that is to copy the DataTable - but then i loose the ability to write back that table since its setter is not called when something has gotten edited.

EDIT #2:

I recreated this example to show the error i have in another program and i just found out that what crashes is actually related with the scrollbar. If i change the ammount of displayed data to a low number so that there is no scrollbar, the code will not crash.

Comment: Do you get an exeption? If so, please edit your question and add the exeption message and stacktrace.

Comment: By design a background thread cannot access a UI object.  I suspect it is crashing with it tries to update the UI.  The UI does not check for proper thread every time so you might some update to lead you to believe that is not the problem.  But it does hang fast and in a bad way.  Not saying for sure that is the problem but I can tell that I had similar problem with similar symptoms.  What I did was make the UI RO then process a copy in the background and then bind the UI to the processed copy in the call back and make the UI RW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following change to the viewmodel solves the problem.

I am now using a copy for wpf to work on and only note the canges should they occur. This code has an issue with the poorly refined change mechanism - but that is beyond the scope of this question.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private SomeBackgroundThing thing;

    private DataTable wpftable;
    public DataTable table
    {
        get
        {
            lock (wpftable)
            {
                return wpftable;
            }

        }

        set
        {
            lock (wpftable)
            {
                wpftable = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel(SomeBackgroundThing thing)
    {
        wpftable = thing.table.Copy();
        this.thing = thing;
        thing.Changed += new EventHandler(thing_Changed);
    }

    void thing_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            DataTable wpftablecopy = wpftable.Copy();
            DataTable thintablecopy = thing.table.Copy();
            int rowcount = wpftablecopy.Rows.Count;
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < rowcount; row++)
                {
                    if (wpftablecopy.Rows[row][col] != thintablecopy.Rows[row][col])
                        wpftable.Rows[row][col] = thintablecopy.Rows[row][col];
                }
            }
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("table"));
        }
    }
}
```